# Why can't i click the "register-selection" in bootstrap and JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I am  making a website and I want to display an alert if the "register-selection" is clicked. But I can't do it. Firstly; I tried to do it with Jquery but it did not work. After that; I tried it with the vanilla Javascript. But it did not work either. I tried to find the solution on the web and ChatGPT but I couldn't find it again. How can I solve my Problem ?

```js
var RegisterButton=document.getElementById("register-selection");


    RegisterButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
        RegisterButton.style.color="red";
    })
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #0A0A0A !important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 6rem;
}


#register-login-selection{
    padding-top: 15rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 5rem;
    word-break: break-all;
}


#register-selection{
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    word-break: break-all;
}


#register-selection>h1{
    color: #FFF08D;
}



#login-selection{
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    word-break: break-all;
}


#login-selection>h1{
    color: #FFF08D;
}

#login-form{
    width: 30%;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    padding-left: 3rem;
    padding-right: 3rem;
    background-color: #0A0A0A;
    border: 0.1rem solid #292929;
}

label{
    color: #FFF08D;
}

input{
    background-color: #0A0A0A !important;
    border-color: #292929 !important;
    color: #6b6b6b !important;
}

.form-group{
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}

button{
    background-color: #FFF08D !important;
    color: #0A0A0A !important;
    border-color: #FFF08D !important;
}


button:hover{
    background-color: #1A1A1A !important; 
    color: #FFF !important;
}


#register-form{
    width: 30%;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    padding-left: 3rem;
    padding-right: 3rem;
    display: none;
    background-color: #0A0A0A;
    border: 0.1rem solid #292929;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="register-login-selection" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="register-selection" class="">
        <h1>Register</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="login-selection" class="">
        <h1>Log In</h1>
    </div>
</div>



<form id="login-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>


<form id="register-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">asd</button>
</form>
```

Comment: To start with, your HTML is invalid. Run it through a validator to fix your errors

Comment: remove the duplicate body tag

Comment: And your script works fine. The color gets changed, it's just that the H1 child also has a color with a greater specificity, and it overrides the color change of the parent div. Check your browser tools to inspect the elements. Now is also a good time to familiarize yourself with basic browser debugging techniques.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add in the addEventlistener the alert() function as below. Also if you want to change the color of your button use RegisterButton.style.backgroundColor="red" I also edited the answer if you want to change the color of h1 title in #register-selection

```js
var RegisterButton=document.getElementById("register-selection");
const title = document.querySelector("#register-selection h1")

    RegisterButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
        alert('you clicked register-selection')
        title.style.color = "blue"
        RegisterButton.style.backgroundColor="red";
    })
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #0A0A0A !important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 6rem;
}


#register-login-selection{
    padding-top: 15rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 5rem;
    word-break: break-all;
}


#register-selection{
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    word-break: break-all;
}


#register-selection>h1{
    color: #FFF08D;
}



#login-selection{
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    word-break: break-all;
}


#login-selection>h1{
    color: #FFF08D;
}

#login-form{
    width: 30%;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    padding-left: 3rem;
    padding-right: 3rem;
    background-color: #0A0A0A;
    border: 0.1rem solid #292929;
}

label{
    color: #FFF08D;
}

input{
    background-color: #0A0A0A !important;
    border-color: #292929 !important;
    color: #6b6b6b !important;
}

.form-group{
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}

button{
    background-color: #FFF08D !important;
    color: #0A0A0A !important;
    border-color: #FFF08D !important;
}


button:hover{
    background-color: #1A1A1A !important; 
    color: #FFF !important;
}


#register-form{
    width: 30%;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    padding-left: 3rem;
    padding-right: 3rem;
    display: none;
    background-color: #0A0A0A;
    border: 0.1rem solid #292929;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="register-login-selection" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="register-selection" class="">
        <h1>Register</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="login-selection" class="">
        <h1>Log In</h1>
    </div>
</div>



<form id="login-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>


<form id="register-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">asd</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So your solution was to put an alert in the OP's code?

Comment: I think tha's what he was asking for. He clearly said he 'wants to display an alert'. Also I  made the background color change to red

Comment: @j08691 I also edited the code to change the h1 title color